# Locate a value in R dataframe based on other column values

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data frame in R

```
data.frame(age = 18,19,29,
     rate = 1.2,4.5,6.8
     sex = "male","female","male")
```

I would like to get the rate associated with values age =18 and sex = male. Is there a way I can index with those values and be able to do this with any pair of age and sex values.

I can do this in dpylr using filter and select commands but this is too slow for what I'm trying to do

Comment: What have you tried already? I'm not sure why it would be too slow

Comment: @camille filter then select

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example that includes the code you're trying to debug, not just a description of it

Answer (score 3):

assuming that df is your dataframe:

```
df[(df$age == 18 & df$sex == 'male'),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `subset`.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df1 <- subset(df,df$age==18 & df$sex=='male')
```

And then

```
View(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

your example data.frame is not properly working, here's one ;)
first you can subset the data, then calculate how many rows you have in that subset versus the main set.

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(18,19,29),
           rate = c(1.2,4.5,6.8),
           sex = c("male","female","male"),
           stringsAsFactors = F)
df_sub <- subset(df, age==18 & sex %in% "male")
df_rate <- nrow(df_sub)/nrow(df)
```

Though if you say filter and select are too slow, you might want to convert your data.frame into a data.table, they are normally faster than data.frames.

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- as.data.table(df)
nrow(dt[age==18 & sex %in% "male"])/nrow(dt)

# or more data.table-like:

dt[age==18 & sex %in% "male", .N] / dt[,.N]
```